# Client-server socket program not experiencing deadlock as expected

Tags: java, sockets, deadlock

I have an example socket program. The client just sends numbers and the server echoes them back.

Client:

```
public class Client {
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;

public Client(String hostname, int port) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket(hostname, port);

    //Create a BufferedReader with buffer size of 1
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()), 1);
    out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
}

public void sendRequest(String x) throws IOException {
    out.print(x + "\n");
    out.flush(); 
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    in.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
}

public String getReply() throws IOException {
    String reply = in.readLine();
    return reply;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 4949);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            System.err.println("Sending: "+i);
            client.sendRequest(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            client.getReply();
        }

        client.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public Server(int port) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
}

private void handle(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    System.err.println("client connected");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    // Create a PrintWriter with buffer size 1
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), 1));

    try {
        for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
            out.print(line + "\n");
            out.flush();
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}

public void serve() throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        // block until a client connects
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            handle(socket);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(); // but don't terminate serve()
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Server server = new Server(4949);
        server.serve();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This may seem like an obvious question, but why is the input buffer to the Client not filling up and causing deadlock? The Client sends 10000 numbers before ever reading any replies. Wouldn't this cause the client's receive buffer to fill up, also causing the server's sending buffer to fill up? I even make the buffer size for the BufferedReader and BufferedWriter as small as possible.However, when I run this code, there is no deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're overlooking the existence of the socket send buffer at the sender, and the socket receive buffer at the receiver. These are in the kernel, and they can clearly hold all the server's output between them.

Comment: To clarify, these are separate buffers from the ones that I am supposedly setting the size of in Java, correct?

Comment: Yes, they are in the kernel.